# Issue with putting correct data into correct SQL columns using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I have a code written that will read in a delimited txt file and then parse through the data and use that information to update a Microsoft SQL server table.

Code shown below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using FileHelpers;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;

namespace prototype_using_filehelpers
{

    class ManagerReport
    {

        [DelimitedRecord("|")]
        [IgnoreEmptyLines()]
        [IgnoreFirst()]
        [IgnoreLast(2)]


        public class ManagerReportNames
        {


            public int? MASTER_VALUE_ORDER;
            public int? MASTER_VALUE;
            public string RESORT;
            public int? CS_HEADING_COUNT_MASTER;
            public int? CS_FS_ARR_ROOMS_MASTER;
            public int? CS_FS_DEP_ROOMS_MASTER;
            public int? CS_FS_NO_ROOMS_MASTER;
            public int? CS_FS_GUESTS_MASTER;
            public int? CS_FS_TOTAL_REVENUE_MASTER;
            public int? CS_FS_ROOM_REVENUE_MASTER;
            public int? CS_FS_INVENTORY_ROOMS_MASTER;
            public int? CF_FS_PERC_OCC_ROOMS_MASTER;
            public int? CF_FS_AVG_ROOM_RATE_MASTER;
            public int? LAST_YEAR_01;
            public int? SUB_GRP_1_ORDER;
            public string SUB_GRP_1;
            public string DESCRIPTION;
            public string AMOUNT_FORMAT_TYPE;
            public string PRINT_LINE_AFTER_YN;
            public int? HEADING_1_ORDER;
            public int? HEADING_1;
            [FieldOptional]
            public string HEADING_2;
            [FieldOptional]
            [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Decimal, ".")]
            public decimal? SUM_AMOUNT;
            [FieldOptional]
            public float? FORMATTED_AMOUNT;


        }

        static void ProcessFilesCSVFiles(string originalPath, string destinationPath)
        {


            // first check if path exists
            if (!Directory.Exists(originalPath))
                // doesn't exist then exit, can't copy from something that doesn't exist
                return;
            var copyPathDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(originalPath);
            // using the SearchOption.AllDirectories will search sub directories
            var copyPathCSVFiles = copyPathDirectory.GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            // loops through directory looking for txt files
            for (var i = 0; i < copyPathCSVFiles.Length; i++)
            {
                // get the file
                var csvFile = copyPathCSVFiles[i];
                //sets lines to the files full extention so it can then be called at a later time
                string lines = csvFile.FullName;

                // read the csv file line by line
                FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(ManagerReportNames));
                var records = engine.ReadFile(lines) as ManagerReportNames[];


                foreach (var record in records)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(record.RESORT);
                    Console.WriteLine(record.FORMATTED_AMOUNT);
                    // This allows us to split what column a row goes into based on whether it is a day month or year
                    string Heading = record.HEADING_2;
                    string Group = record.SUB_GRP_1;
                    string column;
                    if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "OCC_PERC")
                    {
                        column = "Percent_Rooms_Occupied";
                    }
                    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "OCC_PERC_WO_CH")
                    {
                        column = "Percent_Rooms_Occupied_minus_Comp_and_House";
                    }
                    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "ADR_ROOM")
                    {
                        column = "ADR";
                    }
                    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "ADR_ROOM_WO_CH")
                    {
                        column = "ADR_minus_Comp_and_House";
                    }
                    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "ROOMREV_AVL_ROOMS_MINUS_OOO")
                    {
                        column = "Revenue_per_Available_Room_minus_OOO";
                    }
                    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "TOTAL_REVENUE")
                    {
                        column = "Total_Revenue";
                    }
                    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "ROOM_REVENUE")
                    {
                        column = "Room_Revenue";
                    }
                    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "FOOD_BEV_REVENUE")
                    {
                        column = "Food_And_Beverage_Revenue";
                    }
                    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "OTHER_REVENUE")
                    {
                        column = "Other_Revenue";

                    }
                    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "PHYSICAL_ROOMS")
                    {
                        column = "Total_Rooms_in_Hotel";

                    }
                    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "OCC_ROOMS")
                    {
                        column = "Rooms_Occupied";

                    }
                    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "OCC_MINUS_COMP_HU")
                    {
                        column = "Rooms_Occupied_minus_Comp_and_House_Use";

                    }
                    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "COMP_ROOMS")
                    {
                        column = "Complimentary_Rooms";

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        column = "";
                    }




                    // SQL connection. Creates connection and command and inserts the values taken from the File Helper engine into the SQL table
                    SqlCommand cmd;
                    SqlConnection conn;


                    conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=hureports01;Initial Catalog=hureports;Integrated Security=True");
                    conn.Open();
                    var sqlCommand = string.Format(@"MERGE [HEWreport] AS target USING (select @Property_ID as Property_ID, @val as {0}) AS source ON (target.Property_ID = source.Property_ID) WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET {0}= source.{0}
                                                    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (Property_ID, {0}) VALUES (source.Property_ID, source.{0});", column);
                    cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCommand, conn);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Property_ID", record.RESORT);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val", record.FORMATTED_AMOUNT);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }




                // creates a variable that combines the the directory of the new folder with the file name
                var destinationFilePath = Path.Combine(destinationPath, csvFile.Name);
                // This loop prevents duplicates. If a file is already in the folder, it will delete the file already in there and move this one in.
                // Shouldn't be an issue since each file will have a different name
                if (File.Exists(destinationFilePath))
                {
                    File.Delete(destinationFilePath);
                }
                // moves it to the new folder
                csvFile.MoveTo(destinationFilePath);


            }
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            ProcessFilesCSVFiles(@"C:\Users\btajfel\Documents\Opera\Hotels", @"C:\Users\btajfel\Documents\Opera\Completed Hotels");


        }
    }
}
```

I'm only really focused on `RESORT`, `HEADING_2`, `SUB_GRP_1`, and `FORMATTED_AMOUNT`.

What I wanted to implement was have one row with the the value for `RESORT` under `Property_ID` since all rows from the same txt will have the same property id, and then depending on the values of `HEADING_2` and `SUB_GRP_1`, the `FORMATTED_AMOUNT` for the specific row containing those two values will go into one column, and then the `FORMATTED_AMOUNT` for the row containing the next two specific values for `HEADING_2` and `SUB_GRP_1` will go in the column directly next to it.

It is working for the `Property_ID` and the first column but then i get an error next to `cmd = ExecuteNonQuery()` that says:

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll Additional information: Incorrect syntax
>   near ')'."

I'm not sure if it's because something with my code doesn't work or if I made a small mistake or something.

Comment: Why don't you put a break point just after the sqlCommand = assignment and then copy and past the command text out and run it in SQL directly. It looks like it may be a simple formatting issue.

Comment: i actually tried using cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync() and it works for now. Would it make sense that this solved it?

Comment: No, not really. Maybe you had some old assembles that the compiler was not picking up as having changed source - did you do a clean and rebuild maybe? I did count up all the brackets and do a quick sanity check and it did look ok.

Comment: After changing it to  cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync() it worked once and updated all of the columns that i wanted but now it won't add new rows when I run it with a different file

Comment: @Tab Alleman But I didn't change any of the values for the columns but immediately after running it using the Async it worked great. The problem I'm having now is that it won't update rows anymore. It will read the file and run through everything but no matter what file I use it won't update the rows and just leaves it as that one i used the first time that worked

Comment: @TabAlleman could it be an issue with the code itself. It seems as if after it sets column to the first value it's not looping back through the if statement to check for what the next rows column value should be

Comment: so what should I have as my ELSE statement. It won't let me not have an ELSE statement and I don't want it to do something else in the situation                             where it is ELSE because there are a lot of values that don't fall into those categories and I don't want to use them

Comment: If ELSE can be reached, then you need to build your SQL string in such a way that if `column` is empty, then it doesn't add a second column at all.  In other words, it doesn't generate this:  `INSERT (Property_ID, ) VALUES ...`   That comma after Property_ID is a syntax error.

Comment: @TabAlleman I already know that the ELSE will be reached. The first if will be reached on the first line, then two ELSE's and then the next if and then two ELSE's again. It's in a pattern. However, i only want it to do something when the if is reached. When it's the else I just want to ignore it and then when there are no lines left i want it to just stop

Comment: I think you're saying that if the ELSE is reached, you don't want to execute any sql command at all, just skip it?   If that's the case, then simply code it that way.

Comment: @TabAlleman  how would i do that?

Comment: do you have like an example of what that code would look like? Am i fixing my if statement or making a new or changing my sql command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pseudo-code:

```
if (column != "")
{ do your sql command }
else
{ do something else, or do nothing at all }
```